# How to select from a drop down list AND type in text

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu, textinput

I am making form with a select drop down that lists people's names.

I would also like the form to give you the option to select 'Other' and then actually type in someones name (like a normal text input box) if that person is not available from the list.

I don't want the text input part to appear in a  separate box underneath the drop down list, I would like it all within the same box.

Is it possible to do with this in vanilla javascript and no jquery plugin?

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <br>
    List of people: 
    <select>
      <option>John Doe</option>
      <option>Jane Doe</option>
      <option>Richard Doe</option>
      <option>Other (type name here)</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: You can change drop down to a list, put every single item between a (`<li></li>`) and give `ul` a fixed height using css with `overflow-y: scroll;` you can toggle its height property using jQuery.

Comment: Hi, this list of people will be dynamic and linked to a table in a database. People will come and go off the list, so I can't use fixed height as the height will need to keep changing

Comment: doesn't matter, `overflow-y: scroll;` let user to scroll if number of items exceeding given height. If you want to have a textbox within your drop down list you have no choice but to implement something similar to it .You just need to implement a method to generate your `<li></li>` from records in database.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the code below. It's fully adjustable to your likings.

```js
let list = document.getElementById("list");
let other = document.getElementById("other");

function checkValue() {
    if (list.value === "Other (type name here)") {
        other.style.visibility = "visible";
        list.style.display = "none"
    } else {
        other.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <br />
  List of people:
  <select id="list" onchange="checkValue()">
    <option>John Doe</option>
    <option>Jane Doe</option>
    <option>Richard Doe</option>
    <option>Other (type name here)</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" style="visibility: hidden" id="other" />
  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <br /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: This is perfect for what I am looking for.. only one thing.. instead of the text input box appearing at the right hand side, is it possible to have it within the same box as the drop down list? Sorry my knowledge of JS is not great

Comment: If I change the conditional to say     

function checkValue() {
        if (list.value === "Other (type name here)") {
            other.style.visibility = "visible";
            list.style.visibility = "hidden";
        } else {
            other.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }

this removes the drop down box (which is what I want) however the text input is still placed at the right hand side.

Comment: Instead of visibility, you could also use: `display: none`. In JS: `list.style.display = "none"`. On [this W3Schools site](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) you can see the difference between visibility and display. Hope this helps!

Comment: This works! (I have edited your JS code snippet above to demonstrate). I noticed one other thing though. When you select 'other' enabling you to type text into the box, the drop down arrow  on the right hand side disappears, and it won't let you go back to the list again, even if you delete all the inputted text.. is there any way to make the list re-appear again?

Comment: You could do something like [here](https://codepen.io/brycesnyder/full/WoeVrY) where you can toggle between select or text input. But I don't think there is an easy way to keep the arrows when text input is active.